# Represent File Uploads in API Blueprints

Tags: apiblueprint, apiary.io, apiary

We have an API end point where an image file can be uploaded along with the name of the file (a string) as well as a description (string).

Apiary / API Blueprints won't allow me to have something like:

```
+ Request (multipart/form-data)

  + Headers

              Authorization: [key]

  + Attributes
      + name (string, required) - A human-readable name of the Catalog Item
      + description (string, optional) - A human readable description of the Catalog Item
      + image (file, optional) - An image file corresponding to the Catalog Item
```

I get:

`base type 'file' is not defined in the document`

Is there a way to represent multipart/form-data such as the above in API Blueprints?