# How to add file attribute in request body?

Tags: apiblueprint, apiary.io

I'm trying to document API through apiary.io and I want to add the following request body where there is a file in the form of key-value pair:

[image]

How can I add this file in request body in apiary?

Comment: This seems to be related with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46121493/represent-file-uploads-in-api-blueprints